# Unexpected output at a particular row for a dynamic 2D array

Tags: c

I was solving a programing question for displaying Pascal triangle. In the code, I have set the last element of every row equal to zero. Still, the 6th row produces the output as 50 for the last element. I'm unable to figure out the reason for this. Kindly help. The code is attached.

```c
int ** generate(int A, int *number_of_rows) {

    *number_of_rows = A;
    int i,j,nc=0;
    int **result = (int**)malloc(A * sizeof(int *));


    for(i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        nc=i+1;
        result[i]=(int)malloc(nc*sizeof(int));
        result[i][0]=nc;
        result[i][1] = 1;
        for(j=2;j<nc;j++)
        {

            result[i][j]=result[i-1][j]+result[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Edit:

The first element of every row displays the number of columns in that row.

Comment: You never reset `nc`. Is this intended?

Comment: `result[i-1]` will not work when `i` is 0. Set the first element to `1` and iterate from `i = 1`;

Comment: The inner j loop will start from j=2, i.e. only when i>0 due to the malloc statement in the outer loop.

Comment: There is no 2D array in your code and nothing which can point to one. A pointer is not an array.

Comment: And don't cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C!

Comment: On the first iteration of the loop, you have: `for(i=0;i<A;i++)
    {
        nc=i+1;
        result[i]=(int)malloc(nc*sizeof(int));
        result[i][0]=nc;
        result[i][1] = 1;` so `nc` is 1, so you've just written beyond the bounds of the allocated array, leading to undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int ** generate(int A, int *number_of_cols) {
    int **result = malloc(A * sizeof(int *));
    int nc;//number of columns

    for(int i = 0; i < A; ++i){
        number_of_cols[i] = nc = i + 1;
        result[i] = malloc(nc * sizeof(int));
        result[i][0] = result[i][nc-1] = 1;
        if(i > 1)
            for(int j = 1; j < nc -1; ++j){
                result[i][j] = result[i-1][j-1] + result[i-1][j];
            }
    }
    return result;
}
int main(void){
    int n;
    scanf("%d", &n);

    int *number_of_cols = malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    int **pascal_triangle = generate(n, number_of_cols);

    for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i){
        printf("%*s", 2 * (n-i-1), "");
        for(int j = 0; j < number_of_cols[i]; ++j){
            printf("%4d", pascal_triangle[i][j]);
        }
        puts("");
        free(pascal_triangle[i]);
    }
    free(pascal_triangle);
    free(number_of_cols);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't understand the purpose of passing the ***number_of_row** just to assign it the other parameter address. However, I'd split your main **for** loop in 2:
one to allocate all memory and another to fill it.

```
for(i=0;i<A;i++)
  result[i]=(int)malloc((i+1)*sizeof(int));

result[0][0]=1; //in your code, result[i-1] was accessed with i=0
for(i=1;i<A;i++) {
  result[i][0] = i+1;
  result[i][1] = 1;
  for(j=2;j<i;j++)
    result[i][j] = result[i-1][j] + result[i-1][j-1]; //when j reaches the last value, 
                       //[i-1][j] won't work! So put j<i instead.
  result[i][j] = 1;
}
```

The rest of code was OK, check if this is what you wanted. The resulting triangle shoud be:

```
1
2   1
3   1  1
4   1  2  1
5   1  3  3  1
6   1  4  6  4  1 etc.
```